# For loop that span between two variables in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-science

I am trying to do a series of function but selecting between two variables. I need to first impute the missing values then normalize the variables. To impute I use the following code.

```
for(i in (train$B365A:train$BSA)){
  data[i][is.na(data[i])] <- round(mean(data[i], na.rm = TRUE))
 }
```

so for above, I am trying to impute the missing values, they have approximately 20 variables between them.

I have come up with this but it is not affecting the cells.

```
convert_num <- function(i) {
 i <- as.numeric(i)
}
for (i in c(1:3)){
 convert_num(i)
}
```

The data looks similar to the following 
    hope coal kite
     3    4    5
     2    1    5
right now its class but need to be numeric.It has over 20 variables and 18k row.

Comment: You sure [`impute`](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impute) is the word you meant to use, and not `compute` or maybe `input`? (I'm not a statistician, so I don't know if impute has some specialized statistical definition, but I'm a native English speaker and it's not a word I've ever heard before)

Comment: replacing the NA with the mean, I was using the term used in SAS, sorry. Impute - "assign (a value) to something by inference from the value of the products or processes to which it contributes." Webster dictionary

Comment: `mean(data[i])` when `i` is a single value is relatively meaningless. You won't get much help unless you provide some form of a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), since there is no clear indication of what `data` nor `train` are. (And "impute" is used relatively correctly.) You might look at `zoo::na.approx` or `zoo:na.spline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly the solution to your problem would be the following.

```
data <- data.frame(c1 = c(rbinom(10,5,0.5)),
                   c2 = c(rbinom(10,5,0.5)), 
                   c3 = c(rbinom(10,5,0.5)))
data[2:4,1] <- rep(NA,3);data[c(6,8),2] <- rep(NA,2);data[10,3] <- NA
data

# imput data from c1:c3
for(i in 1:3){
  data[i][is.na(data[i])] <- round(mean(data[,i], na.rm = T))
}
data
data[] <- lapply(data,as.numeric) # transform to numeric
sapply(data,class)
```